# Error inferring build function type during bloc testing

Tags: flutter, testing, bloc

Couldn't infer type parameter 'B'.

Tried to infer 'CounterCubit?' for 'B' which doesn't work:
Type parameter 'B' is declared to extend 'BlocBase' producing 'BlocBase<_>'.
The type 'CounterCubit?' was inferred from:
Parameter 'build' declared as     'B Function()'
but argument is 'CounterCubit? Function()'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `!` in your `build` function should solve the problem.

```
blocTest(
  "The cubit should emit CounterState(counterValue: 1, isIncremented: true)",
  build: () => counterCubit!,
  act: (cubit) => cubit.increment(),
  expect: () => [const CounterState(counterValue: 1, isIncremented: true)],
);
```